# Cast a CustomList<CustomClass> to IList<Interface>

Tags: c#-3.0

(This is .Net 3.5)  I have a class FooList which implements IList and a class FooClass which implements IFoo.  A user requires `IList<IFoo>`.  In my implementation, I create a `FooList<FooClass>`, called X.  How do I code my return so that my `FooList<FooClass> X` becomes his `IList<IFoo>`?

If I try

return X.Cast( ).ToList( );

he gets an `IList<IFoo>`, but it is not my FooList; it is a List, and a new one at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work out, because a `FooList<FooClass>` is not an `IList<IFoo>`.  This is why:

```
var myList = new FooList<FooClass>();
IFoo obj = new SomeOtherFooClass();
IList<IFoo> result = (IList<IFoo>)myList; // hypothetical, wouldn't actually work
result.Add(obj); // uh-oh, now myList has SomeOtherFooClass
```

You need to either make a copy or use an interface that is actually covariant on the contained type, like `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`.  Or, if appropriate, you should declare your `FooList<FooClass>` as an `FooList<IFoo>` from the get-go instead.

Here is a small implementation that demonstrates my second suggestion:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class FooClass : IFoo { }

public class FooList<T> : IList<T>
{
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { /* ... */ }
    /* further boring implementation of IList<T> goes here */
}

public static void ListConsumer(IList<IFoo> foos)
{
    foos.RemoveAt(0); // or whatever
}

public static IList<IFoo> ListProducer()
{
    // FooList<FooClass> foos = new FooList<FooClass>(); // would not work
    FooList<IFoo> foos = new FooList<IFoo>();

    foos.Add(new FooClass());

    return foos; // a FooList<IFoo> is an IList<IFoo> so this is cool
}

public static void Demo()
{
    ListConsumer(ListProducer()); // no problemo
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm going to have to do some studying to understand what you are telling me.  

At a higher level, what I am trying to accomplish is this:  A UI coder sees my collection as an IList.  [I can't change that; it is in our contract.]  However, when he codes RemoveAt, for example, I need him to hit FooList.RemoveAt, not List.RemoveAt.

Comment: I added an example that might help illustrate one potential solution.